# How to read request body in OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) in IActionFilter Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am sending AES encrypted request body to controller following is a sample:

```
(using crypto-js) 
{body: "U2FsdGVk186Jj7LySqT966qTdpQZwiR+wR0GjYqBzR4ouFAqP8Dz8UPPTv"}
```

I have created action filter, so whenever the request is posted I can decrypt the request in action filter than pass the decrypted request to the desired controller.

request after decryption :

```
{Name: "admin123" }
```

so how to get encrypted request body in action filter? and how to pass decrypted request body to the controller

I have tried WEB API in ASP.NET core `StreamReader` but it is returning an empty string

I want to pass decrypted request body to the controller

filter

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
    {
        bodyStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    req.Body.Position = 0;
}
```

controller

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<string> MyControllerName(InfoReq info)
{

}
```

class

```
public class InfoReq 
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you need to go for the middleware approach.Read the documentation [Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
if you want to read stream you must have to request.EnableRewind().because of `Request. body` is a read and forward only stream that doesn't support reading the stream a second time.

```
 request.EnableRewind();
```

after reading apply your logic and after that the request you need to add `original stream back on the Response. Body`

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {              
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
     try
        {
            request.EnableRewind();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
            {
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            request.Body = request; 
        }
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0
        
    }
```

You should have to set stream position zero(0)
`request.Body.Position = 0 .` Otherwise, you will get empty body exception.

Comment: How can you return string.Empty in void method ?

Comment: @RamilAliyev007 you can not return a string from a void method. But I guess you wanted to update the request body or query, if that's the case you can simply update the property in the method.

Comment: @mahbuburrahmanrifat  I wrote comment on 22 September 2022, but this post updated on 13 October 2022. Previous version of the this post, void method return the string.Empty. I think post's owner updated the his answer

Answer (score 10):

You can use :

```
var body = context.ActionArguments["info"] as InfoReq ;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. @downvoter. care to comment ?

Comment: I agree that this works. I was wondering how is it possible. But then I looked at the lifecycle of action filters and there I saw it. ActionFilter goes after Model binding therefore Body stream has been already read and data are already parsed. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? what if the attribute is just validating and not returning any value?